# How to share data between multiple threads and processes in Python effectively?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a main thread running `Cmd` from `cmd2`. This allows me to interactively start new threads using `threading.Thread()` performing simulations in "real-time". Every time step the simulation results are `put()` in a `multiprocessing.Queue()`. Additionally I can start live plots using `matplotlib.animate`. I read `matplotlib` is not thread-safe, so the plots run as a `multiprocessing.Process()` and `get()` the simulation results from the queue.

Unfortunately, once items from the queue are collected, they are deleted from the queue and not available for other threads or processes. This means I can send data from the simulation threads to the plotting processes, but can't use the simulation results at the same time in my main thread.

A solution could be to have two queues in each simulation thread: one queue to the main thread and one queue to the plotting process. This doesn't seem to be the optimal solution, but a rather complicated one.

Does anyone have an idea how to realize some kind of thread-safe shared variable every thread and processes can read from and write to?

Comment: It is very hard to follow what you mean by threads and processes. Do you start one or multiple programs? Do you run multiprocessing or multithreading or both?

Comment: How about adding one `queue.Queue` for the main thread to read from?

Comment: @JohanL I am using `threading.Thread()` as well as `multiprocessing.Process()` for different tasks (threads are used for simulations and processes are used for live plots).

Comment: You have a weird setup, usually you'd want to do the CPU bound stuffs like simulations in multi processes, while the UI stuffs like plotting are usually necessarily in the main thread (most UI frameworks requires that you only have a single UI thread).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there are two main ways of sharing data between threads and memory:

- message passing
- shared memory

Python encourages you to avoid writing code that uses shared memory, and if you need to share data between threads and processes, you should just  make a copy of the data and send it through a Queue.

If you need actual shared memory, this is fraught with many perils as you'll necessarily need to deal with locks to avoid problems. Additionally, this may not be possible with many python objects either as all python objects in a process shares a GIL.

> I read matplotlib is not thread-safe

Code that aren't t multihread safe are usually not multiprocess safe either.

> Does anyone have an idea how to realize some kind of thread-safe shared variable every thread and processes can read from and write to?

You don't want to, or if you really have to, use a database.

Comment: While I agree with much of the sentiment of this answer I do think that the sentence  _Code that aren't t multihread safe are usually not multiprocess safe either_ is quite correct. The main reason for functions not being thread safe are shared global state (i.e. global variables and files et c.). Normally there is a much stonger isolation between processes, so that they will not share even global variables or temporary files. Therefore, most of the time, it is quite possible that the code is multiprocess safe without being thread safe.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, especially the comment about "weird setup". I restructured my whole code and start the simulations as different processes which write the simulation results to a queue. The results are collected in another thread and made available to the main thread. I managed to configure matplotlib in a non-blocking way for the live plots, so matplotlib runs in the main thread.